# basic live text input without html <input>'s

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to start a project that requires that the javascript know every word that's typed in. An example of something I would try to accomplish would be that you would type `4 + 4`, the interpreter on the webpage knows what you mean, and automatically puts `= 8` on to the end of that line to show it's computed it, without having to submit anything or press any button.

I've looked into the  element, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel or go against what the spec says. With putting a `<textarea>` as input on top of a canvas, the javascript on the page can only know what is in the textbox when the user submits the text. Is there anything out there that would help with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "the javascript on the page can only know what is in the textbox when the user submits the text" — No, JavaScript can access its value at *any* time.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough. What I meant was it doesn't know when someone types in something until they submit the text. If I'm wrong, then i'd love to know where I could learn about how to use a regular `<textarea>` like that.

Comment: Never mind. Did some more research and discovered the `onkeypress` attribute for textareas. I didn't really know what I was asking until you made that comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of a textarea you can just access it via the DOM:

```
var textArea = document.getElementById("id-of-textarea");
```

To the textarea you can attach different eventlisteners, and in your case I would use `onkeypress`

```
textArea.onkeypress = function () {
   var ta_value = textArea.value;
   alert(ta_value);
}
```

Of course you'd have to write your own interpreter, I wouldn't recommend running `eval` on the input...

Answer (score 0):

try adding a hidden input element and give it the focus when the page load is complete, and use the `onkeyup` handler to do whatever u want.